# Any way to find the function of a VarDecl?

Tags: c++, clang

I was wondering if it's possible to find if a VarDecl was initialised in a function and if so, get that function name as a FunctionDecl or a string.

Ive looked through http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ValueDecl.html but I cannot find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    ///This function will be called whenever a variable is found in the ASTReader
  static void RegisterVarDecl(void *v)
  {
    VarDecl* var = (VarDecl*)v;
    if (var->isLocalVarDecl()){
      variables_.push_back(new string(var->getNameAsString().c_str()));
    }
  }
```

This returns the name of the variable for me nicely whilst

```
  static void RegisterFunctionDecl(void * v)
  {
    FunctionDecl* func = (FunctionDecl*)v;
    funcs_.push_back(new string(func->getNameInfo().getName().getAsString()));
    if (func->getNumParams() > 0){
      for (int i = 0; i < func->getNumParams(); ++i){
        params_.push_back(new string(func->getParamDecl(i)->getNameAsString()));
      }
    }
    num_params_.push_back(func->getNumParams());
  }
```

returns the function and the arguments of that function.

I was wondering if there was a way perhaps in the FunctionDecl to specify what VarDecls exist inside or if I can find the FunctionDecl a VarDecl belongs to.

Comment: Could you please add an short example, what  you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`VarDecl`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1VarDecl.html) is a subclass of [`Decl`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Decl.html) which has a function [`getParentFunctionOrMethod()`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Decl.html#a64c7ec888871588c93536bfd22774b30). This function returns a [`DeclContext *`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1DeclContext.html) which is a superclass of [`FunctionDecl`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionDecl.html). To downcast the `DeclContext *` to a `FunctionDecl *` you should use the functions from [llvm/Support/Casting.h](http://llvm.org/doxygen/Casting_8h.html).